# Не могу разобраться с библиотекой android-crop для обрезки фото

Tags: android

Задача такая. При логине надо нажать на картинку, выбрать фото, вырезать лицо и поместить в картинку. Я нашел, на мой взгляд, самую хорошую либу (наивный) [ссылка](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop).

но сразу возникла проблема, нету метода `Crop.of`. На стеке мне посветовали так:

```
new Crop(source).output(destination).start(getActivity());
```

но опять ничего не работает. Я жму на картинку, выбираю фотку из галереи и.....все.
Как починить эту беду?

Comment: почему нет метода `Сrop.of()` ? В исходнике он есть ( строка 37 класса `Crop`)

Comment: действительно етсь. в исходнике на гит хабе. Но когда вы подтяние либу градлом в проект, то в том классе нет его

Comment: Не вы один [его потеряли](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/issues/108) , да ... Ну да ладно . Что вы делаете после того , как сделали то , что посоветовали на "стеке" ?

Comment: это я и задал вопрос на гит хабе. что я делаю? да все так как у него в екзампле. только заменив этот метод на тот что посоветовали. галерея открывается но при нажатии на фотку просто я снова вижу свой активити без ничего. он веть 4 дня назад чтото менял в екзампле, неужеле накосячил

Comment: Лучше всего дождаться , что ответят на ваш issue на трекере , чем городить костыли , я так считаю.Он потом может исправит , если "накосячил" и опять нужно будет все переделывать

Comment: вобщем запустил я его екзампл. он там либу как проект подключает и все работает. и если через градл - то фигушки. так что наверное корявый градл он сделал, через который не то чтото подтягивается(причем нормально без ошибок). щас буду подключать как проект к своему